# Polygon Shapely package python issues with airflow, giving false even though point is inside polygon

Tags: python, web-scraping, geometry, airflow, shapely

I'm facing an issue when running a portion of my code that involves the use of Shapely package (for polygon and points) in python on Airflow.

What the code does:
It converts a url to point (using a function) then checks if that point is inside a polygon. Locally the point is showing `True`. But on Airflow I keep getting `False` on Airflow

```
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
from shapely.geometry import Point

def convert_url_to_point(x):
    split1 = x.split("=")
    split2 = split1[1].split("%2C")
    x_coordinates = split2[0]
    y = split2[1]
    y_coordinates = y.split("&")[0]
    x_coordinates = float(x_coordinates)
    y_coordinates = float(y_coordinates)
    point = Point(x_coordinates, y_coordinates)
    return point

url = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=33.76846398%2C-84.38438488&zoom=17&size=256x256&language=en&sensor=false&client=google-maps-frontend&signature=BaDj2xFv1Bv6pHNDtGF0v29UYe0"

x = convert_url_to_point(url)


check_polygon = Polygon[(34.127493 -83.81768199999999, 34.135484999999996 -83.808328, 34.145086 -83.797005, 34.165076 -83.773452, 34.180189 -83.75564399999999, 34.186807 -83.747799, 34.230622 -83.69633499999999, 34.241549 -83.6835, 34.261873 -83.659479, 34.295276 -83.620115, 34.296971 -83.62122099999999, 34.300548 -83.624253, 34.30131 -83.625099, 34.301938 -83.624835, 34.302838 -83.624725, 34.303992 -83.624133, 34.304471 -83.624131, 34.305212 -83.624358, 34.305839 -83.62475699999999, 34.306221 -83.625191, 34.306411 -83.62563399999999, 34.306968 -83.632243, 34.312761 -83.64183299999999, 34.314789000000005 -83.643915, 34.315872 -83.644272, 34.319744 -83.64807900000001, 34.321487 -83.649292, 34.323153999999995 -83.649628, 34.327477 -83.649292, 34.333309 -83.647789, 34.335167 -83.647774, 34.338004999999995 -83.649002, 34.340328 -83.649475, 34.343715 -83.651441, 34.346311 -83.651674, 34.34882 -83.651306, 34.350346 -83.65259499999999, 34.353123 -83.656013, 34.354733 -83.65679899999999, 34.355877 -83.65879100000001, 34.355915 -83.66082800000001, 34.357201 -83.663589, 34.359623 -83.66534399999999, 34.362728000000004 -83.666512, 34.364329999999995 -83.66845699999999, 34.3661 -83.66967, 34.367241 -83.668625, 34.36795 -83.666756, 34.369331 -83.66546600000001, 34.370777000000004 -83.665405, 34.372646 -83.663628, 34.37624 -83.66261300000001, 34.378761 -83.660187, 34.38007 -83.659805, 34.381753 -83.659798, 34.386856 -83.660252, 34.390739 -83.659981, 34.391791999999995 -83.65888199999999, 34.399746 -83.655563, 34.401586 -83.654022, 34.404517999999996 -83.648033, 34.406428000000005 -83.64542900000001, 34.412528 -83.643546, 34.415003999999996 -83.640513, 34.415867 -83.636392, 34.416229 -83.634349, 34.418112 -83.630946, 34.418994 -83.626464, 34.419513 -83.625445, 34.419317 -83.623212, 34.422426 -83.620944, 34.425225 -83.619677, 34.426676 -83.61954300000001, 34.43047 -83.617053, 34.431748 -83.615251, 34.444922999999996 -83.624897, 34.464163 -83.638541, 34.503596 -83.666398, 34.503602 -83.666415, 34.504457 -83.75676700000001, 34.504796999999996 -83.777703, 34.513696 -83.77760500000001, 34.514096 -83.788604, 34.504754 -83.78847900000001, 34.505494 -83.843405, 34.497021999999994 -83.843315, 34.477317 -83.873901, 34.477238 -83.87490600000001, 34.475644 -83.877684, 34.468788 -83.88760400000001, 34.459936 -83.887627, 34.459861 -83.898901, 34.459804999999996 -83.90995, 34.469184999999996 -83.90984300000001, 34.469345000000004 -83.93188599999999, 34.460529 -83.931898, 34.460114000000004 -83.920662, 34.451126 -83.92068499999999, 34.451206 -83.931313, 34.449003000000005 -83.93509300000001, 34.437286 -83.956448, 34.437907 -83.957018, 34.436121 -83.961492, 34.436171 -83.963473, 34.433882000000004 -83.966321, 34.432904 -83.970371, 34.432722 -83.975146, 34.431088 -83.97373, 34.424021 -83.970678, 34.422810999999996 -83.970893, 34.41874 -83.975926, 34.419061 -83.97851800000001, 34.418389000000005 -83.980649, 34.417041 -83.983285, 34.411603 -83.984818, 34.410755 -83.984365, 34.411528000000004 -83.979247, 34.408592999999996 -83.975603, 34.406551 -83.974756, 34.405108 -83.971836, 34.401784 -83.971522, 34.398998999999996 -83.972768, 34.397946000000005 -83.976472, 34.395041 -83.97796, 34.39076 -83.978534, 34.389018 -83.98120300000001, 34.386117999999996 -83.98360799999999, 34.382959 -83.984332, 34.381464 -83.982117, 34.380671 -83.979373, 34.379234999999994 -83.977223, 34.377131 -83.979614, 34.374109999999995 -83.980368, 34.372981 -83.979178, 34.371644 -83.979421, 34.369599 -83.980861, 34.368739 -83.980862, 34.368140999999994 -83.979341, 34.364664000000005 -83.97631700000001, 34.362838 -83.97618, 34.361895000000004 -83.97706099999999, 34.359538 -83.98145799999999, 34.357828999999995 -83.981433, 34.357152 -83.97960400000001, 34.356576000000004 -83.976238, 34.353265 -83.975274, 34.35011 -83.972988, 34.347657 -83.971915, 34.344120000000004 -83.968531, 34.340746 -83.967572, 34.339628999999995 -83.966853, 34.339943 -83.965438, 34.342667999999996 -83.962579, 34.34324 -83.961275, 34.342713 -83.960172, 34.340247 -83.960032, 34.334011 -83.957077, 34.334055 -83.96263, 34.334313 -84.01854200000001, 34.334348999999996 -84.044143, 34.334401 -84.05573199999999, 34.334423 -84.066513, 34.33461 -84.114866, 34.334756 -84.148473, 34.334871 -84.176378, 34.335156 -84.258075, 34.380992 -84.257586, 34.380881 -84.323042, 34.380839 -84.347459, 34.380814 -84.36182099999999, 34.380767999999996 -84.37890300000001, 34.380699 -84.390826, 34.373292 -84.392224, 34.373292 -84.39236600000001, 34.373266 -84.400774, 34.380492 -84.400724, 34.380551000000004 -84.411969, 34.380593 -84.424526, 34.38707 -84.424525, 34.387994 -84.424523, 34.388192 -84.442126, 34.380392 -84.442326, 34.380518 -84.46319100000001, 34.380595 -84.475711, 34.381492 -84.58263000000001, 34.385768 -84.582658, 34.412191 -84.58283, 34.41259 -84.65323199999999, 34.412887 -84.69917, 34.412968 -84.733878, 34.396495 -84.73411800000001, 34.397345 -84.79897700000001, 34.397627 -84.82593100000001, 34.397715000000005 -84.83715699999999, 34.396601000000004 -84.862863, 34.396778999999995 -84.87494000000001, 34.396458 -84.889753, 34.396311 -84.89572199999999, 34.398598 -84.89619, 34.398731 -84.91939, 34.398687 -84.928564, 34.398721 -84.932611, 34.398747 -84.93475600000001, 34.398955 -84.952546, 34.384190000000004 -84.953743, 34.384378000000005 -84.97044100000001, 34.397733 -84.970777, 34.397631 -84.979632, 34.384772 -84.98005400000001, 34.384558 -84.98991600000001, 34.392453 -84.98926, 34.392528999999996 -84.995599, 34.392446 -85.005775, 34.369142 -85.005607, 34.34708 -85.005235, 34.347112 -85.02310200000001, 34.325990000000004 -85.023342, 34.319713 -85.023021, 34.316932 -85.02329499999999, 34.305261 -85.023219, 34.275462 -85.023533, 34.258289000000005 -85.023891, 34.258206 -85.015528, 34.251131 -85.015606, 34.251201 -85.02394699999999, 34.246177 -85.024101, 34.213384999999995 -85.023813, 34.213248 -85.02631600000001, 34.213621999999994 -85.044658, 34.207257 -85.044889, 34.183818 -85.045249, 34.167485 -85.045282, 34.166171000000006 -85.045259, 34.117882 -85.046428, 34.096412 -85.046871, 34.082881 -85.047046, 34.082811 -85.03311, 34.082941 -84.999014, 34.082771 -84.976125, 34.082591 -84.95152900000001, 34.082553000000004 -84.939087, 34.078398 -84.939043, 34.078198 -84.93004300000001, 34.082597 -84.92994300000001, 34.082497 -84.922742, 34.074818 -84.92684799999999, 34.071698 -84.92874300000001, 33.996085 -84.960089, 33.995656 -84.96029899999999, 33.9895 -84.962887, 33.973501 -84.969418, 33.971565999999996 -84.97021600000001, 33.951392999999996 -84.97868299999999, 33.952635 -85.04983299999999, 33.904488 -85.05031, 33.904356 -85.048982, 33.904447 -85.04835899999999, 33.904327 -85.036684, 33.900931 -85.036735, 33.875118 -85.037125, 33.870305 -85.037401, 33.842061 -85.037695, 33.841588 -85.037768, 33.829027 -85.037674, 33.826527 -85.037752, 33.811941999999995 -85.037926, 33.812321999999995 -85.049031, 33.779959999999996 -85.049591, 33.755525 -85.04991899999999, 33.740742 -85.050278, 33.738403000000005 -85.050332, 33.732319 -85.050498, 33.714632 -85.050889, 33.714968 -85.066544, 33.710696999999996 -85.066469, 33.694611 -85.106786, 33.693267999999996 -85.110158, 33.691403 -85.114846, 33.691348 -85.114985, 33.691509 -85.12745600000001, 33.691423 -85.129688, 33.699778 -85.129441, 33.699915999999995 -85.13503, 33.69992 -85.135166, 33.699982 -85.137012, 33.700016999999995 -85.139027, 33.698721 -85.143125, 33.698593 -85.143535, 33.688109000000004 -85.177313, 33.683017 -85.1936, 33.678955 -85.206565, 33.669908 -85.235598, 33.663317 -85.256273, 33.659815 -85.265588, 33.658894000000004 -85.26844200000001, 33.652087 -85.289742, 33.6531163257259 -85.3382006083928, 33.5803388694423 -85.3237922987933, 33.5741594828964 -85.3225689183808, 33.5376467594031 -85.315340215273, 33.5376461241702 -85.3153400895111, 33.535897999999996 -85.314994, 33.5349512560896 -85.31484348771991, 33.530218 -85.314091, 33.529807 -85.313999, 33.482884000000006 -85.304439, 33.4774207256388 -85.3033886220355, 33.4469350716994 -85.29752740090429, 33.440601931981604 -85.2963097812195, 33.428079319201196 -85.29390216343329, 33.427981 -85.270624, 33.427973 -85.266313, 33.427225 -85.19754300000001, 33.426789 -85.116129, 33.426631 -85.099121, 33.426428 -85.080699, 33.425506 -85.01535799999999, 33.375115 -84.995773, 33.374688 -84.995536, 33.302163 -84.96820100000001, 33.277053 -84.958646, 33.282365000000006 -84.95858299999999, 33.282353 -84.95689399999999, 33.282277 -84.948815, 33.265653 -84.94881, 33.265608 -84.954578, 33.25123 -84.948988, 33.224693 -84.939015, 33.224634 -84.933196, 33.224623 -84.93226, 33.224244 -84.894317, 33.223858 -84.862135, 33.215892 -84.861977, 33.207541 -84.86219799999999, 33.207433 -84.871954, 33.20496 -84.870345, 33.201639 -84.870016, 33.198388 -84.86917, 33.195662 -84.869904, 33.195915 -84.867099, 33.198115 -84.865138, 33.199143 -84.862382, 33.191173 -84.862359, 33.191043 -84.852304, 33.215517 -84.852345, 33.22359 -84.85236, 33.223511 -84.835008, 33.223471999999994 -84.824733, 33.223406 -84.812765, 33.223346 -84.795278, 33.223194 -84.75429100000001, 33.223172999999996 -84.747761, 33.223098 -84.7427, 33.223222 -84.736834, 33.222969 -84.715068, 33.231187 -84.71497, 33.231493 -84.696779, 33.223065000000005 -84.69689100000001, 33.222735 -84.674613, 33.226496000000004 -84.674514, 33.226428000000006 -84.669476, 33.229708 -84.669374, 33.229636 -84.665998, 33.229481 -84.651461, 33.222518 -84.65150600000001, 33.22244 -84.635725, 33.222149 -84.62177700000001, 33.221703999999995 -84.576212, 33.221687 -84.57595500000001, 33.221534999999996 -84.565975, 33.221055 -84.502352, 33.219638 -84.50263299999999, 33.218958 -84.500585, 33.216578999999996 -84.501162, 33.215857 -84.502581, 33.214973 -84.502105, 33.215266 -84.500902, 33.21367 -84.499585, 33.212196999999996 -84.499511, 33.211579 -84.49803, 33.210561 -84.498232, 33.209907 -84.49682, 33.207181 -84.496144, 33.206383 -84.49730699999999, 33.205092 -84.497132, 33.204703 -84.498202, 33.201648 -84.49844300000001, 33.201696000000005 -84.496914, 33.200351 -84.494525, 33.200006 -84.492889, 33.198564000000005 -84.492319, 33.197586 -84.490539, 33.195614 -84.492582, 33.196513 -84.493826, 33.194502 -84.49483599999999, 33.191998 -84.496812, 33.189439 -84.495132, 33.187418 -84.495013, 33.186371 -84.496133, 33.183865999999995 -84.496783, 33.186298 -84.493112, 33.186784 -84.49041899999999, 33.18679 -84.487268, 33.187832 -84.484516, 33.18846 -84.481302, 33.190502 -84.480455, 33.191361 -84.478219, 33.193399 -84.477968, 33.195849 -84.476274, 33.19833 -84.47648000000001, 33.20064 -84.47545799999999, 33.201909 -84.473497, 33.200741 -84.470475, 33.20178 -84.470277, 33.201242 -84.468728, 33.199638 -84.467935, 33.199289 -84.46674499999999, 33.2019 -84.462388, 33.201093 -84.45881800000001, 33.202636 -84.455285, 33.203592 -84.455232, 33.206353 -84.452935, 33.208267 -84.452768, 33.208889 -84.451336, 33.208496999999994 -84.40447900000001, 33.208311 -84.393467, 33.200271 -84.39363, 33.200359999999996 -84.373141, 33.189625 -84.373685, 33.189591 -84.364072, 33.189541999999996 -84.352267, 33.189349 -84.325591, 33.189234 -84.26834000000001, 33.189019 -84.24818499999999, 33.188905 -84.227503, 33.183926 -84.224205, 33.182281 -84.223857, 33.179388 -84.224277, 33.179357 -84.216673, 33.179332 -84.210068, 33.179349 -84.20655, 33.179133 -84.181361, 33.178948999999996 -84.143857, 33.17862 -84.123981, 33.202824 -84.123767, 33.242748 -84.123152, 33.244515 -84.122998, 33.244424 -84.118123, 33.248731 -84.118117, 33.2488 -84.122675, 33.252668 -84.122623, 33.254484999999995 -84.120802, 33.266005 -84.108982, 33.272301 -84.10258499999999, 33.285646 -84.08899100000001, 33.286499 -84.09144599999999, 33.289924 -84.09300999999999, 33.292097999999996 -84.09721400000001, 33.293819 -84.097137, 33.298190999999996 -84.102582, 33.30209 -84.10244, 33.301998 -84.095147, 33.301874 -84.08854699999999, 33.298008 -84.085509, 33.300447999999996 -84.081383, 33.301873 -84.080238, 33.301817 -84.07369200000001, 33.317609999999995 -84.073, 33.317609999999995 -84.063532, 33.309805 -84.063591, 33.309668 -84.061322, 33.317741999999996 -84.053701, 33.319410999999995 -84.05366, 33.321513 -84.053636, 33.326126 -84.053651, 33.329549 -84.05364499999999, 33.329549 -84.045907, 33.331317 -84.045798, 33.331327 -84.042654, 33.333501 -84.042663, 33.333495 -84.044597, 33.337109000000005 -84.044485, 33.336544 -84.04266899999999, 33.341113 -84.04253299999999, 33.341381 -84.040261, 33.342833 -84.038296, 33.342766 -84.03313399999999, 33.361645 -84.032682, 33.361641 -84.032049, 33.36161 -84.025807, 33.361397 -84.024891, 33.360985 -84.024281, 33.358465 -84.025183, 33.35699 -84.024553, 33.356879 -84.021323, 33.358109999999996 -84.01825600000001, 33.359025 -84.014903, 33.360494 -84.012636, 33.362894 -84.010993, 33.366196 -84.008215, 33.368345 -84.007604, 33.36826 -84.00126, 33.368639 -83.99969200000001, 33.368288 -83.989016, 33.367472 -83.986012, 33.368189 -83.98403, 33.370155 -83.982998, 33.370184 -83.98214899999999, 33.371734000000004 -83.98084300000001, 33.372004 -83.978716, 33.373954 -83.976838, 33.374741 -83.976915, 33.374751 -83.971784, 33.375153999999995 -83.96437399999999, 33.377247 -83.96437399999999, 33.378506 -83.963748, 33.380306 -83.96732800000001, 33.381699 -83.966024, 33.385127000000004 -83.96600000000001, 33.385191999999996 -83.973218, 33.407556 -83.973128, 33.407582 -83.96311, 33.411414 -83.96311, 33.419185999999996 -83.96311, 33.419242 -83.954029, 33.425225 -83.954029, 33.425290000000004 -83.943516, 33.441783 -83.94349799999999, 33.441865 -83.932746, 33.444515 -83.932599, 33.444666999999995 -83.929152, 33.444194 -83.923913, 33.440943 -83.921621, 33.439062 -83.918932, 33.436714 -83.919787, 33.434333 -83.919686, 33.434216 -83.91883100000001, 33.436357 -83.91630500000001, 33.435652000000005 -83.915027, 33.433355 -83.916168, 33.43122 -83.91448000000001, 33.429349 -83.914413, 33.427426000000004 -83.915267, 33.426109000000004 -83.910607, 33.423769 -83.910842, 33.421727000000004 -83.912269, 33.419323999999996 -83.912733, 33.41768 -83.912299, 33.418242 -83.910444, 33.417833 -83.908286, 33.416053000000005 -83.906565, 33.413796999999995 -83.90605699999999, 33.412737 -83.904966, 33.412258 -83.90300400000001, 33.410706 -83.900378, 33.410364 -83.898227, 33.407305 -83.895108, 33.402023 -83.895904, 33.396725 -83.895081, 33.395184 -83.893908, 33.394018 -83.892363, 33.392933 -83.888926, 33.391278 -83.885547, 33.391132 -83.88181800000001, 33.390305 -83.879502, 33.388546999999996 -83.87799999999999, 33.385938 -83.877263, 33.383179 -83.877392, 33.378725 -83.874213, 33.378035 -83.873289, 33.3773 -83.868905, 33.377718 -83.86562099999999, 33.377054 -83.8643, 33.375668 -83.864319, 33.372791 -83.866592, 33.370442 -83.864104, 33.368278000000004 -83.863058, 33.368817 -83.859854, 33.367239 -83.853942, 33.370016 -83.854889, 33.371679 -83.856949, 33.372584 -83.85215, 33.374257 -83.84774300000001, 33.375881 -83.84783900000001, 33.379286 -83.846522, 33.380998999999996 -83.845487, 33.383762 -83.842237, 33.390002 -83.83783299999999, 33.390845 -83.836445, 33.392926 -83.83154499999999, 33.393462 -83.831024, 33.394775 -83.831863, 33.39586 -83.833138, 33.399747999999995 -83.840191, 33.40258 -83.842537, 33.404922 -83.84375, 33.405044000000004 -83.836975, 33.407883 -83.836884, 33.407753 -83.845024, 33.414721 -83.84520699999999, 33.415076 -83.82826800000001, 33.419185999999996 -83.830792, 33.421524 -83.830872, 33.422686 -83.828603, 33.426289000000004 -83.828278, 33.428265 -83.826134, 33.429947 -83.826424, 33.433386999999996 -83.82347800000001, 33.437263 -83.824922, 33.438037 -83.823385, 33.436321 -83.82096899999999, 33.437003999999995 -83.819344, 33.436237 -83.8172, 33.436706 -83.81626999999999, 33.434657 -83.81219499999999, 33.436336 -83.808384, 33.440829 -83.807374, 33.446371 -83.791949, 33.452495 -83.77127800000001, 33.454652 -83.76951, 33.455636 -83.767439, 33.459322 -83.76274699999999, 33.467028000000006 -83.753556, 33.476479 -83.742085, 33.480862 -83.736687, 33.488518 -83.70474300000001, 33.492191 -83.709514, 33.495096000000004 -83.712281, 33.500895 -83.705275, 33.497758000000005 -83.70264300000001, 33.498296999999994 -83.701135, 33.494824 -83.69711099999999, 33.493252000000005 -83.696541, 33.49069 -83.69347900000001, 33.489143 -83.692642, 33.485794 -83.688858, 33.484796 -83.689177, 33.483117 -83.687601, 33.48276 -83.685874, 33.482971 -83.682419, 33.483897 -83.679039, 33.487225 -83.674644, 33.494428000000006 -83.683006, 33.496784000000005 -83.683143, 33.502142 -83.684602, 33.506194 -83.686566, 33.507867 -83.685958, 33.510564 -83.688077, 33.512204 -83.687523, 33.522247 -83.683634, 33.52622 -83.68219599999999, 33.571176 -83.677669, 33.571834 -83.677717, 33.575946 -83.68118, 33.577913 -83.681443, 33.579378999999996 -83.683003, 33.579508000000004 -83.684202, 33.580906 -83.685979, 33.582435 -83.687087, 33.584416999999995 -83.685851, 33.586681 -83.686022, 33.588559000000004 -83.687386, 33.596919 -83.68089599999999, 33.604988 -83.674501, 33.611874 -83.669067, 33.626125 -83.657788, 33.649296 -83.639195, 33.674944 -83.618844, 33.698899 -83.60011999999999, 33.711408 -83.590189, 33.77839 -83.53694, 33.781544 -83.534669, 33.796119 -83.526386, 33.796626 -83.524019, 33.798814 -83.52138199999999, 33.807919 -83.512385, 33.811124 -83.511491, 33.81776 -83.505928, 33.817603999999996 -83.509598, 33.815437 -83.51017, 33.817719 -83.515694, 33.816608 -83.517578, 33.819668 -83.520126, 33.818245000000005 -83.521927, 33.819578 -83.523894, 33.821194 -83.529213, 33.820923 -83.533165, 33.821521999999995 -83.533836, 33.822792 -83.532829, 33.823238 -83.531235, 33.824272 -83.53138, 33.825584 -83.532753, 33.827969 -83.537224, 33.830894 -83.541611, 33.831309999999995 -83.542801, 33.832527 -83.54310600000001, 33.833431 -83.54521899999999, 33.833637 -83.54705, 33.835882 -83.549495, 33.836292 -83.55085, 33.838833 -83.55365, 33.839046 -83.555359, 33.840674 -83.55832, 33.842484000000006 -83.561775, 33.844177 -83.56262199999999, 33.844916999999995 -83.564125, 33.846981 -83.566338, 33.846985 -83.569855, 33.846573 -83.571632, 33.847408 -83.573265, 33.848999 -83.574646, 33.851135 -83.57473, 33.852394 -83.57414200000001, 33.854424 -83.574875, 33.858868 -83.579369, 33.859913 -83.581581, 33.862614 -83.582565, 33.864441 -83.584869, 33.863503 -83.58641, 33.864182 -83.588432, 33.861931 -83.589027, 33.863361 -83.590622, 33.864445 -83.590233, 33.867638 -83.587334, 33.871798999999996 -83.587349, 33.873540999999996 -83.587065, 33.874939000000005 -83.586143, 33.876971999999995 -83.586189, 33.878281 -83.584106, 33.880096 -83.584305, 33.881847 -83.582314, 33.883608 -83.583613, 33.883282 -83.58645600000001, 33.88147 -83.590538, 33.881347999999996 -83.594666, 33.882835 -83.596283, 33.881481 -83.60035699999999, 33.881972999999995 -83.60198199999999, 33.883419 -83.602035, 33.883095000000004 -83.603523, 33.881622 -83.604729, 33.88118 -83.608765, 33.881341 -83.611475, 33.881904 -83.61281, 33.883316 -83.615234, 33.882957 -83.615974, 33.883813 -83.61841899999999, 33.885517 -83.619232, 33.884702000000004 -83.622066, 33.885643 -83.625504, 33.88493 -83.626427, 33.886646999999996 -83.63030400000001, 33.891253000000006 -83.631709, 33.892067 -83.630608, 33.897038 -83.631271, 33.898540000000004 -83.63188199999999, 33.900112 -83.633476, 33.901051 -83.633377, 33.90276 -83.635712, 33.904793 -83.63604699999999, 33.904216999999996 -83.6371, 33.908306 -83.638855, 33.908297999999995 -83.640112, 33.90703 -83.642318, 33.906940000000006 -83.644249, 33.905599 -83.642074, 33.904796999999995 -83.644775, 33.906197999999996 -83.64703100000001, 33.907691 -83.64434200000001, 33.924919 -83.612972, 33.945389 -83.575526, 33.947936 -83.570786, 33.950138 -83.56669000000001, 33.954638 -83.558384, 33.965912 -83.537385, 33.997684 -83.54979399999999, 34.003128000000004 -83.55107, 34.003192999999996 -83.551106, 34.031684000000006 -83.56318399999999, 34.031864 -83.563277, 34.032326 -83.564444, 34.031953 -83.567251, 34.031022 -83.568708, 34.031110999999996 -83.570462, 34.031401 -83.571111, 34.035298 -83.57271899999999, 34.036597 -83.573709, 34.037155 -83.573851, 34.03782 -83.573725, 34.038582 -83.573332, 34.039057 -83.573438, 34.039563 -83.577393, 34.039653 -83.57950500000001, 34.041058 -83.584158, 34.038641 -83.58398000000001, 34.03918 -83.586321, 34.038074 -83.58801, 34.0373 -83.590236, 34.037046999999994 -83.59420300000001, 34.036477000000005 -83.59526, 34.036635 -83.59783399999999, 34.037376 -83.598722, 34.0353 -83.600538, 34.036553999999995 -83.602908, 34.037723 -83.603166, 34.038696 -83.604815, 34.039064 -83.607352, 34.03817 -83.609085, 34.041256 -83.611671, 34.042652000000004 -83.61108399999999, 34.044441 -83.611725, 34.044712 -83.614708, 34.045553999999996 -83.61558000000001, 34.046921000000005 -83.614418, 34.047384 -83.61729, 34.046389000000005 -83.620403, 34.046843 -83.621737, 34.045138 -83.62510999999999, 34.04545 -83.627898, 34.044756 -83.630326, 34.046189 -83.630903, 34.046209000000005 -83.6349, 34.04595 -83.636133, 34.047691 -83.637335, 34.048301 -83.638625, 34.048662 -83.642185, 34.049283 -83.643778, 34.050854 -83.64376800000001, 34.050682 -83.645927, 34.049982 -83.646637, 34.047373 -83.646872, 34.045986 -83.647835, 34.046581 -83.65258, 34.047478000000005 -83.65508299999999, 34.050045000000004 -83.656479, 34.052792 -83.65654, 34.053288 -83.658043, 34.052338 -83.660484, 34.052273 -83.66324, 34.048903 -83.66311999999999, 34.048229 -83.66566800000001, 34.048337 -83.66912099999999, 34.053036 -83.673454, 34.053593 -83.67619300000001, 34.052494 -83.676926, 34.052319 -83.678955, 34.051442 -83.679633, 34.049306 -83.678688, 34.047304 -83.679911, 34.047538 -83.681664, 34.046942 -83.684937, 34.04847 -83.68666400000001, 34.051025 -83.685755, 34.053442 -83.685513, 34.053674 -83.68807, 34.052119 -83.690044, 34.051615999999996 -83.691806, 34.05292 -83.693963, 34.054914000000004 -83.693727, 34.056255 -83.69459499999999, 34.05579 -83.695991, 34.053734000000006 -83.69651800000001, 34.052608 -83.698143, 34.054121 -83.699641, 34.054378 -83.70070600000001, 34.052914 -83.70201899999999, 34.048705 -83.702473, 34.046291 -83.704426, 34.046158 -83.707623, 34.045127 -83.70918, 34.045984000000004 -83.71137900000001, 34.049139000000004 -83.713083, 34.050024 -83.714399, 34.051696 -83.71378299999999, 34.052949 -83.712561, 34.054434 -83.712294, 34.056378 -83.713492, 34.055954 -83.71576, 34.055073 -83.717076, 34.053545 -83.718763, 34.055503 -83.720803, 34.056567 -83.720383, 34.058012 -83.720965, 34.059106 -83.720239, 34.060401 -83.721327, 34.06263 -83.721588, 34.063423 -83.72377, 34.060703000000004 -83.727928, 34.060116 -83.731796, 34.060905 -83.732872, 34.064056 -83.734344, 34.066662 -83.733307, 34.067345 -83.733726, 34.066395 -83.737205, 34.066673 -83.738564, 34.069496 -83.740578, 34.069191 -83.742798, 34.068027 -83.743431, 34.065909999999995 -83.74209599999999, 34.065243 -83.74233199999999, 34.065292 -83.745293, 34.064919 -83.748451, 34.064201000000004 -83.75138100000001, 34.06657 -83.75924300000001, 34.066609 -83.761739, 34.066163 -83.762831, 34.06487 -83.76331, 34.065292 -83.765134, 34.066448 -83.76753199999999, 34.069234 -83.769041, 34.073040999999996 -83.769705, 34.074234999999994 -83.773836, 34.078378 -83.776534, 34.079819 -83.777977, 34.083892 -83.78609200000001, 34.086628000000005 -83.79051199999999, 34.087837 -83.791351, 34.088299 -83.79143499999999, 34.093533 -83.78993100000001, 34.093578 -83.78993299999999, 34.100041 -83.792046, 34.101136 -83.793524, 34.102072 -83.795982, 34.102833000000004 -83.79980400000001, 34.103049 -83.800169, 34.105676 -83.80312099999999, 34.107694 -83.805762, 34.109614 -83.805693, 34.109404999999995 -83.807783, 34.111269 -83.809889, 34.112851 -83.811757, 34.113701 -83.815174, 34.114585 -83.814394, 34.115520000000004 -83.81110799999999, 34.117293 -83.81299200000001, 34.120515000000005 -83.81218199999999, 34.121502 -83.815208, 34.122532 -83.816528, 34.12688 -83.815996, 34.127493 -83.81768199999999)]

inside_polygon_boolean = check_polygon.contains(x)
print(inside_polygon_boolean)
```

Comment: Airflow doesn’t do anything magic to your workflow. But it might be running in a different environment with different versions of shapely or other packages, or you might be accidentally passing different data or arguments into your function, or maybe you have old or different version of your code running within airflow. You’ll need to diagnose what’s going on yourself - hopefully this gets you started!

Comment: @MichaelDelgado I'm using the same package versions for Shapely on both cases, any advice you can give me I tried debugging for a lot of time before I posted this, can't find any reasonable difference.

Comment: Sounds rough. I’m not an airflow expert but I’d imagine it would be helpful to those that are if you could post much more about your airflow setup. Right now there’s no way for us to reproduce and diagnose the behavior you’re seeing, and if the difference really is being driven by the airflow config then we’d really need to see this in order to understand the problem.

Comment: What about logging `x.wkt` and `inside_polygon_boolean.wkt` in Airflow? Are values identical to those you'd get locally?  Wait..  is that the actual code you have in Airflow and it runs through? Shouldn't there be   `check_polygon = wkt.loads('POLYGON((34.127493 -83.81768199999999, ... ))')` ? I mean you don't have list of tuples there, its like a non-string wkt.

Comment: @margusl I haven't tried that, I wasn't aware of all the functions available in the shapely package. can you give me any resources where I can check if I can use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the actual code in Airflow, try changing polygon to valid *Well Known Text* to load it  with `wkt.loads()` :

```py
check_polygon = wkt.loads('POLYGON ((34.127493 -83.81768199999999, 34.135484999999996 -83.808328, 34.145086 -83.797005, ..., 34.127493 -83.81768199999999))')
```

Alternatively, create an ordered sequence of point tuples for `Polygon` constructor:

```py
check_polygon = Polygon([(34.127493, -83.81768199999999), (34.135484999999996, -83.808328), (34.145086, -83.797005), ..., (34.127493, -83.81768199999999)])
```

Currently you seem to have a mix of both approaches.

##### Some additional context

To create a [Shapely polygon](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#polygons), you can pass a list of point tuples ( `[(x1,y1), (x2,y2), ...]` ) to the class constructor. You can also serialize existing geometric objects to [Well Known Text](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#well-known-formats) strings or import objects in *wkt* form from other sources and load those with `wkt.loads()` :

```py
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
from shapely import wkt

# Polygon class constructur, takes list of point tuples:
polygon_a = Polygon([(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 2), (2, 0), (0, 0)])
print(f'Well Known Text: "{polygon_a.wkt}"')

# deserialize a geometric object from wkt string, note the quotes and how 
# point coordinates are separated by <space>  
polygon_b = wkt.loads('POLYGON ((0 0, 0 2, 2 2, 2 0, 0 0))')

if polygon_a == polygon_b:
  print ('Polygons are equal')

## Output:
# Well Known Text: "POLYGON ((0 0, 0 2, 2 2, 2 0, 0 0))"
# Polygons are equal
```

You seem to have a wkt-string as a base with some modifications on top of it, though with my sample coordinates editor / IDE would warn about it even before running, it would also just throw `SyntaxError`:

```py
# wkt: 'POLYGON ((0 0, 0 2, 2 2, 2 0, 0 0))' 
# incorrect tranformation to Polygon():
polygon_c = Polygon[(0 0, 0 2, 2 2, 2 0, 0 0)]
```

```py
File "<ipython-input-37-a734f32944de>", line 3
    polygon_c = Polygon[(0 0, 0 2, 2 2, 2 0, 0 0)]
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You happen to have negative y-coordinates, so your coordinate list actually gets evaluated:

```
# first 2 coordinate pairs as an example:
(34.127493 -83.81768199999999, 34.135484999999996 -83.808328,)
# exactly the same as 
(34.127493-83.81768199999999, 34.135484999999996-83.808328,)
# and would be evaluated to sequence of two, i.e. (x1-y1, x2-y2):
(-49.69018899999999, -49.67284300000001)
```

This might trick your IDE to not warn you about error, but this would still throw `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable` during execution.

##### To conclude

***If*** this is how you construct your polygon in Airflow instance, your Airflow Task is likely to fail not because your point is outside of the polygon, but because it throws an error.

Comment: I haven't used the function wkt.laods(). Can you tell me the purpose for using it? I tried reading the documentation but still not clear completely

Comment: @fsaa , your code sample throws exceptions and your polygon definition seems to be originating from a wkt-string that you should load with `wkt.loads()` . After changing your polygon definition to wkt-notation & loading it with `wkt.loads()`, it runs fine and test passes with `True`.  Eddited the answer with some context and background information.